# ListView with separate row layouts not generating views properly

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, baseadapter

Hi i have created a listview,In that i inflated four layout, my data set is images, text,audio and Video. so i inflating the layouts accordingly.Once the data is coming from Api,and images is being cached,and audio video and text is being stored in folder and sqlite respectively. But when i open second time the listview showing the data randomly or sometime unordered. even sometime not showing whole data. here is my adapter's code.

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

ArrayList<ListModel> myList = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
LayoutInflater inflater;
Context context;
int flag = 0;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM1 = 1;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM2 = 2;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM3 = 3;
private static final int TYPE_ITEM4 = 4;
private String url;
private String vPath;
private MediaPlayer mp;



public ListViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<ListModel> myList) {
    this.myList = myList;
    this.context = context;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this.context);

}


int type;

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    ListModel listModel = myList.get(position);
    String data = listModel.getType();
  /*  if (data.equals("Text")) {
        return type1;
    } else if (data.equals("Image")) {
        return type2;

    }return 0;*/

    if (data.equals("Text")) {
        type = TYPE_ITEM1;
    } else if (data.equals("Image")) {
        type = TYPE_ITEM2;
    } else if (data.equals("Audio")) {
        type = TYPE_ITEM3;
    }else if(data.contains("Video")){
        type=TYPE_ITEM4;
    }

    return type;

}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return myList.size() + 1;
}


@Override
public int getCount() {
    return myList.size();
}


@Override
public ListModel getItem(int position) {
    // return myList.get(position);

    if (position >= myList.size()) {
        return null;
    }
    return myList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(final int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    TextView textView = null;
    ImageView imageView = null;
    VideoView vPlayer = null;
    Button pause = null;
    Button play = null;

    int type = getItemViewType(position);
    System.out.println("getView " + position + " " + v + " type = " + type);
    if (v == null) {
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        if (type == TYPE_ITEM1) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_text, null);
            textView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        } else if (type == TYPE_ITEM2) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_image, null);
            imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        } else if (type == TYPE_ITEM3) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_audio, null);
            play = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.btn_play);
            pause = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.stop);
        } else if (type == TYPE_ITEM4) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_video, null);
            vPlayer = (VideoView) v.findViewById(R.id.video_player);

        }
        holder.textView = textView;
        holder.videoPlayer = vPlayer;
        holder.imageView = imageView;
        holder.play = play;
        holder.stop = pause;
        v.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
    }
    ListModel model = myList.get(position);
    if (holder.play != null) {
        holder.play.setId(position);

    }if (holder.videoPlayer!=null){
        holder.videoPlayer.setId(position);
    }if (holder.stop!=null){
        holder.stop.setId(position);
    }

    String datatype = model.getType();

    if (datatype.equals("Text")) {
        holder.textView.setText(model.getData());
    } else if (datatype.equals("Image")) {
        UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.imageView, model.getData());
    } else if (datatype.equals("Audio")) {
        url = model.getData();
    }else if (datatype.equals("Video")){
        vPath=model.getData();

    }
    if (holder.play != null) {
        holder.play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int i = view.getId();
                ListModel model = myList.get(i);
                String audioUri = model.getData();
                new PlayMusicFromPath().execute(audioUri);
            }
        });
        if (holder.stop!=null){
        holder.stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });}
        if (holder.videoPlayer!=null) {

            final ViewHolder finalHolder = holder;
            holder.videoPlayer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    int videoId = view.getId();
                    ListModel model1 = myList.get(videoId);
                    String videoUrl = model1.getData();
                    finalHolder.videoPlayer.setVideoPath(videoUrl);



                }
            });
        }

    }

    return v;
}


public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView;
    public ImageView imageView;
    public Button play, stop;
    public VideoView videoPlayer;


}


public void audioPlayer(String fileName) {
    //set up MediaPlayer
    mp = new MediaPlayer();

    try {
        mp.setDataSource(fileName);
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        mp.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    mp.start();
}

class PlayMusicFromPath extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    // Show Progress bar before downloading Music
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // Shows Progress Bar Dialog and then call doInBackground method

    }

    // Download Music File from Internet
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... f_url) {
        audioPlayer(f_url[0]);

        return null;
    }

    // Once Music File is downloaded
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        System.out.print(file_url);

    }
}
```

the views are as below
list_Video contains one videoview
list_audio contains two buttons play and pause.
list_text contains one textView
and list_image containing one imageview 
the `Logcat` is

```
addInArray been called, this = android.widget.ListView{443bacd0 VFED.VC. .F....ID 0,0-540,838 #7f0a006d app:id/listview}call stack =
java.lang.Throwable: addInArray
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addInArray(ViewGroup.java:3786)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3740)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInLayout(ViewGroup.java:3687)
        at android.widget.ListView.setupChild(ListView.java:1862)
        at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1815)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:698)
        at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:759)
        at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1631)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2150)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15131)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutHorizontal(LinearLayout.java:1877)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1653)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15131)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15131)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
        at android.support.v7.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:493)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15131)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15131)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1888)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1742)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1651)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15131)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:515)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:450)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:15131)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4862)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2323)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2029)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1192)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6231)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:788)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:591)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:774)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

and i am seeing these lines also..
`myprojectname while﹕ A105 to many`

Comment: please post ur layout

Answer (score 1):

in view type count, you need to provide the different type views count and not the list count. In your case, it should be four (Text, Image, Audio and video)

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return 4;
}
```

Comment: it is repeating same datas twice. for testing i have four items text audio video and image. but text and image is not showing only video and audio layouts showing.

Comment: @Akshaychauhan but you are having only 4 different type of views right?

Comment: @Akshaychauhan also your getView method implementation is wrong..you need to revisit the same.

Comment: please guide me what can i do with `getView()`

Comment: first time when i load the data from API the listview is perfect but second time i passing the data from sqlite. file name for audio and video and image is auto loading from cache and text is storing in sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

This is a common problem with list views. 
first ill explain what is happening.
When your list view scrolls it will try to reuse the viewholder instead of creating an entire new one. 
if item at position 1 is an image and the list reuses the view at position 5 but position 5 is video data so if you dont hide the image view then both the image view and the video view will show up. It seems random but nothing in programming is random unless you program it that way.

Here is my suggestion. To make it work with what you have you need to explicitly set all other views in the view holder to `visibility="gone"` except the view that you need for that items position.

```
holder.textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
holder.vPlayer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
holder.play.setVisibility(View.GONE);
holder.pause.setVisibility(View.GONE);

if (datatype.equals("Text")) {
    holder.textView.setText(model.getData());
    holder.textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else if (datatype.equals("Image")) {
    UrlImageViewHelper.setUrlDrawable(holder.imageView, model.getData());
    holder.imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else if (datatype.equals("Audio")) {
    url = model.getData();
    holder.play.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    holder.pause.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}else if (datatype.equals("Video")){
    vPath=model.getData();
    holder.vPlayer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

A better solution would be to use a recycler view and defferent view holders for each view.

Here is an example of one of my recycler adapters. You can read about them [here.](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html)

```
public class ProgramRecyclerAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

/** 
This is an abstract class that all of my viewholders inherit from. 
This is a contract telling me that any subclasses that inherit from this
base class are required to write their own `public void bind(int position,
Program program);` method. 
*/
abstract class ProgramBaseViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    public ProgramBaseViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
    }

    public abstract void bindDataToView(int position, Program program);
}
```

`@Bind` and Butterknife.bind is part of a viewbinding library called Butterknife. This usage of "bind" is the equivalent of your `findViewById()` calls.

```
/**
This is the Airtime view that holds airtimes. It is a view holder that
inherits from my base view holder and implements its own version if bind.
*/
class AirtimeViewHolder extends ProgramBaseViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.program_airtimes)
    TextView mProgramAirtimes;

    static final int viewType = 0;

    public AirtimeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        /**This call to butterknife can be replaced with an
        itemView.findViewById(R.id.yourview) */
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    //This is where you set your text and hide or show your views.
    @Override
    public void bindDataToView(int position, Program program) {
        List<Airtime> airtimes = program.getAirtimes();
        if (!airtimes.isEmpty()) {
            mProgramAirtimes.setText(Utils.getFriendlyAirtimes(airtimes));
        } else {
            mProgramAirtimes.setText(
                    Utils.getFriendlyAirTime(program.getAirtime()));
        }
    }
}

/**
This is the Description view that holds descriptions. It is a view holder  
that inherits from my base view holder and implements its own version if    
bind.
*/
class DescriptionViewHolder extends ProgramBaseViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.description_card_layout)
    TextView mProgramDescription;

    static final int viewType = 1;

    public DescriptionViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindDataToView(int position, Program program) {
        mProgramDescription.setText(Html.fromHtml(program.getFullDescription()));
    }
}
//This is another type of view with another different type of layout.
class HostsViewHolder extends ProgramBaseViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.card_view_host_name)
    TextView mProgramHostName;

    static final int viewType = 2;

    public HostsViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindDataToView(int position, Program program) {
        mProgramHostName.setText(program.getHosts().get(position - 2).getDisplayName());
    }
}
//Again another type of view extending my base view.
class CategoriesViewHolder extends ProgramBaseViewHolder {
    @Bind(R.id.program_categories)
    TextView mProgramCategories;
    static final int viewType = 42;

    public CategoriesViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        ButterKnife.bind(this, itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void bindDataToView(int position, Program program) {
        List<Category> categoryList = program.getCategories();
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (Category category : categoryList) {
            stringBuilder.append(category.getTitle())
                    .append(" ");
        }
        mProgramCategories.setText(stringBuilder.toString());
    }
}

//This is where the normal looking recycler view code comes in.
private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private Program mProgramData;
private int mNextProgramId;

public ProgramRecyclerAdapter(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
}
```

In your situation you determine your view types by looking at the data. I based my view types on position and some data.

```
/**This method is where I am determining what view type each item in my list 
will be. I wanted a single airtimes view followed by a single description 
view and then X amount of hosts views and a single category view. I return 
position in the third else if because the position helps me determine which 
host name to display in the bindDataToViews call of the HostViewHolder.*/
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (position == AirtimeViewHolder.viewType) {
        return AirtimeViewHolder.viewType;
    } else if (position == DescriptionViewHolder.viewType) {
        return DescriptionViewHolder.viewType;
    } else if (position > DescriptionViewHolder.viewType
            && position <= DescriptionViewHolder.viewType + getHostsNum()) {
        return position;
    } else {
        return CategoriesViewHolder.viewType;
    }
}

//This method figures out how many hosts will be displayed
private int getHostsNum() {
    if (mProgramData != null) {
        return mProgramData.getHosts().size();
    }
    return 0;
}
// This method determines if I will show a category view or not.
private int getCategoriesNum() {
    if (mProgramData != null && mProgramData.getCategories().size() > 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}

/**This returns haw many items will be in the list. 1 Airtime view, 1 
Description view, x amount of Host views and 0 or 1 category views */
@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return 2 + getHostsNum() + getCategoriesNum();
}

/** This returns the appropriate View holder for the requested view type that 
was set by getItemViewType(). I pass the inflated parent view and the data.     
*/
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    if (viewType == AirtimeViewHolder.viewType) {
        return new AirtimeViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.airtime_card_layout, parent, false));
    } else if (viewType == DescriptionViewHolder.viewType) {
        return new DescriptionViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.description_card_layout, parent, false));
    } else if (viewType > DescriptionViewHolder.viewType
            && viewType <= DescriptionViewHolder.viewType + getHostsNum()) {
        return new HostsViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.hosts_card_layout, parent, false));
    } else
        return new CategoriesViewHolder(mInflater.inflate(R.layout.categories_card_layout, parent, false));
}

/*This method is what ties everything together. After I ensure that the data 
is not null I call bindDataToView on a ProgramBaseViewHolder. Depending on 
which type of subclass it is will determine which overridden bindData code to 
use. */
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    ProgramBaseViewHolder baseViewHolder = (ProgramBaseViewHolder) holder;
    if (mProgramData != null) {
        baseViewHolder.bindDataToView(position, mProgramData);
    }
}

//This is used to set the data for this program
public void setProgramData(Program program) {
    mProgramData = program;
}

public Program getProgramData() {
    return mProgramData;
}

public boolean isEmpty() {
    return mProgramData == null;
}
}
```

This is the Airtime layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">  
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"> 
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/airtimes_label"
        android:textSize="18dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"/> 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/program_airtimes"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />  
</LinearLayout>
```

This is my host layout. You will notice that I am not using most of the views here because this is an app in progress.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/host_card_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin"
    card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@color/white"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="8dp" />
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/host_image"
            android:layout_width="112dp"
            android:layout_height="112dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/details"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/host_image"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/card_view_host_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
                android:layout_gravity="left" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/card_view_hosts_programs"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:layout_gravity="left"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[image: This is the view that is produced with some data. The Categories view is cut off but it is there.]